# Interfaces polymorphism in Delphi

Tags: delphi, oop, interface, delphi-7

I have two interfaces one deriving from antoher:

```
type
  ISomeInterface = interface
    ['{5A46CC3C-353A-495A-BA89-48646C4E5A75}']
  end;

  ISomeInterfaceChild = interface(ISomeInterface)
    ['{F64B7E32-B182-4C70-A5B5-72BAA92AAADE}']
  end;
```

Now I have a procedure which parameter is ISomeInterface like:

```
procedure DoSomething(SomeInterface: ISomeInterface);
```

I want to check if SomeInterface is ISomeInterfaceChild. `Is` operator is not supported in interfaces in Delphi 7 and I can't use `Supports` here neither. What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can indeed use `Supports`. All you need is:

```
Supports(SomeInterface, ISomeInterfaceChild)
```

This program illustrates:

```
program SupportsDemo;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  ISomeInterface = interface
    ['{5A46CC3C-353A-495A-BA89-48646C4E5A75}']
  end;

  ISomeInterfaceChild = interface(ISomeInterface)
    ['{F64B7E32-B182-4C70-A5B5-72BAA92AAADE}']
  end;

procedure Test(Intf: ISomeInterface);
begin
  Writeln(BoolToStr(Supports(Intf, ISomeInterfaceChild), True));
end;

type
  TSomeInterfaceImpl = class(TInterfacedObject, ISomeInterface);
  TSomeInterfaceChildImpl = class(TInterfacedObject, ISomeInterface, ISomeInterfaceChild);

begin
  Test(TSomeInterfaceImpl.Create);
  Test(TSomeInterfaceChildImpl.Create);
  Readln;
end.
```

**Output**

```
False
True
```

Answer (score 4):

Why do you say you can't use the [`Supports`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SysUtils.Supports) function? It seems to be the solution, it has an overloaded version which takes `IInterface` as the first parameter so

```
procedure DoSomething(SomeInterface: ISomeInterface);
var tmp: ISomeInterfaceChild;
begin
  if(Supports(SomeInterface, ISomeInterfaceChild, tmp))then begin
     // argument is ISomeInterfaceChild
  end;
```

should do what you want.

Comment: If all that is required is to check whether or not the interface supports `ISomeInterfaceChild` then you are using the wrong overload. You should use the two parameter overload as I demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: Well, I went with the assumption that if you need to check is the parameter `ISomeInterfaceChild` you also need to work with it as `ISomeInterfaceChild`. Othervise the check doesn't quite make sense, it shouldn't matter and thus checking for it might indicate an design problem.

Comment: @ain: Not necessarily. Sometimes interfaces are used to advertise characteristics about the containing object without actually exposing new functions for them. In that case, simply checking for the mere presence of the supported interface is enough.